# Determining Interrupt index in Linux kernel 4+

Tags: linux, interrupt-handling, zynq

I have an interrupt connected to the GIC of an ARM processor in a Xilinx Zynq-7000. Previously, the recommended way to use an interrupt in Linux would be to use

```
request_irq(INTERRUPT_INDEX,interrupt_handler,0,DEVICE_NAME,DEVICE_ID);
```

where INTERRUPT_INDEX would be a number you could obtain from your hw_definition file.

However, in more recent Linux kernels, apparently IRQs use virtual indicies, which means the number listed in the hw_definition file no longer corresponds to the interrupt I am trying to monitor.

How can I determine the proper values to use for INTERRUPT_INDEX, DEVICE_NAME, and DEVICE_ID in order to register an interrupt handler to a given GIC interrupt?